# How to send custom Long and Lat to Google Maps API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I can initialise the Google Maps API as such, using predefined Longitudes and Latitudes:

```
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -28.643387, lng: 153.612224},
    zoom: 12
  });
}
```

However, I want to send this script my own Long and Lat that I've gotten from another function. So far I've tried:

```
//GLOBAL VARS
var usrpos = "";   

function handleGetCurrentPosition(location){
    var lat = location.coords.latitude;
    var long = location.coords.longitude;
    var usrpos = "lat: " + lat + ", lng: " + long;
}

var map;
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {usrpos},
    zoom: 12
  });
}
```

and:

```
//GLOBAL VARS
var usrlat = "";
var usrlong = "";

window.onload = function(){
    if(navigator.geolocation)
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(handleGetCurrentPosition);
}

function handleGetCurrentPosition(location){
    var usrlat = location.coords.latitude;
    var usrlong = location.coords.longitude;
}

var map;
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: usrlat, lng: usrlong},
    zoom: 12
  });
}
```

With no luck.

Would anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you seeing any errors in your Javascript console?

Your first attempt is definitely incorrect because you're passing the coordinate values as one long string, instead of 2 separate parameters: `var usrpos = "lat: " + lat + ", lng: " + long;`

I don't see any problem with your second attempt, except for this:

Maybe you haven't posted all of your code, but in the example you provided, the `initMap()` function is not being called, so your map is never initializing. You should wait until the geolocation has completed and then initialize the map like this:

```
function handleGetCurrentPosition(location){
  var usrlat = location.coords.latitude;
  var usrlong = location.coords.longitude;
  initMap();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have already established the lat/lng, you don't need to geolocate.  Simply declare them as global variables, then do something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.21"></script>
</head> 
<body>
  <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    lat = 30;//from other function
    long = -90;//from other function
    coords = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,long);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 13,
        center: coords,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(
        document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions
        );

 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

With [the posted code I get a javascript error: `Assertion failed: InvalidValueError: setCenter: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number`.](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/vcrLayu4/)  Because `usrpos` is a string, not a [`google.maps.LatLng`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng) or a [`google.maps.LatLngLiteral`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngLiteral).  This code will fix that error:

```
//GLOBAL VARS
var usrpos;   

function handleGetCurrentPosition(location){
    var lat = location.coords.latitude;
    var lng = location.coords.longitude;
    usrpos = {lat: lat, lng: lng};
}

var map;
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: usrpos,
    zoom: 12
  });
}
```

However, it isn't clear how the initMap function is being called. Seems like there might be a second issue with the asynchronous nature of the geolocation service.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the function as I have shown below, it will solve your problem. Your mistake was that you didn't use google.maps.LatLng to process your coordinates in a manner that google.maps.Map can accept.

```
var lat = -28.643387;
var lng = 153.612224;

function initMap(lat, lng) {
    var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 12,
        center: coords
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use initMap as a call back in the google maps  tag. Let the api load while you are calling other functions or somehow retrieving your coordinates. Your API script tag should look like this:

```
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY">
</script>
```

Then pass in coordinates to your initMap(lat,lng) function when you are ready to call it. From experience, this API loads quickly.